# Getting access denied issue after site moving to live server in magento?

Tags: database, magento

I have moved the magento website to my live server.

But When i try to open it gives me error like  "http://prntscr.com/ff3yp2".

Can you please help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your database credentials in `app/etc/local.xml` are incorrect or you need to grant privileges to that user+host combo in your database.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Its fixed now Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the MySQL user. I have had this issue in the past with using Magento databases from another server.

Update the password and execute these two commands.

```
CREATE USER 'inkpri_new'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'inkpri_new'@'localhost';
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

This issue occur because of 2 reasons.

1. Incorrect database connection details are mention in app/etc/local.xml file.
2. Mention user don't have all the privileges of that database.

You can check host as well.